# How we can use complex bullets elements in html text area?

Tags: html

How can I insert different complex bullets elements which we use in Microsoft word into html text area?

When I insert them into text area, text area changes its style and replace bullets elements with '?' question mark.

Why html is not identifying complex bullets elements? Textarea is only identifying simple bullets elements.

Comment: Please include sample code showing what you have tried.

Comment: What's this got to do with JS, PHP or CF?

Answer (score 3):

- HTML knows nothing of Microsoft Word's proprietary complex bullet elements.
- HTML knows nothing of Microsoft Word's formatting.
- HTML knows nothing but the plain ASCII text you placed into the textarea.
- There are Rich Text Editors like http://ckeditor.com/ that can convert MS Word content into HTML (you used one similar on the textarea where you entered your question).
- You may also need to ensure your content is rendering using UTF-8 to correctly display your content (and avoid the empty squares, etc.).

Comment: like if i add  complex bullets in LinkedIn, then it convert them into empty square. how and why?

Comment: The empty square or the diamond with a ? in it means the browser does not recognize the character that you attempted to display. If the website in which you're trying to display this content does not give you an RTF editor to convert the MS Word contents, then you have to convert it yourself into plain HTML. This still does not guarantee that your HTML content will display as you intend, since many site filter out HTML content or encode the HTML entities in order to avoid Cross-site Scripting attacks.